# Cannot install any application in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

i have proxy controlled internet. Though i can access internet in firefox in ubuntu after addinf proxy settings , whenever i try to update something in ubuntu through terminal it shows network error. Also i tried installing chrome and also flash plugin for firefox , but these shows errors and i cant even update anything.

Answer (score 1):

That is why you have not manually entered the proxy that you use easily in any browser. You have to set proxy for **Ubuntu** also.

**Here are the steps to set proxy in Ubuntu**

- Open **System Settings** ( search in your dash )
- Chose **Network** ( you can also find the icon of Network form `/usr/share/applications` just double click it to open )
- Then chose **Network Proxy** on the Window.
- Select <kbd>Manual</kbd> form the list. Set your proxy and
- <kbd>Apply System Wide</kbd>
- Thats it.

Now you would be able to download any thing from command line also.